# Select row from List<string> where matches

Tags: c#, string, list, search

I have the following `List<string>`

`List<string> RFD = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("FDIASNC"));`

the file it is reading has this:

`000821031300000000080

001921031300000000080

004221031300000000080

008121031300000000080

009321031300000000080

011221031300000000080

012221031300000000080

0128200313010000330790000033

207721031300000000080`

So what I want is to find a match and select this line, for example if I want to read the line for "0128" it will be RFD[7] manually, but I want to search that line and output the line for manipulation... Any idea?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I found it once I posted, I'm a dumb hehe... thank you for your answers, in 10 min I will select one as the correct :)

Comment: if (t.Any(o => o.Contains("yourvalue")))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to search:

```
var line = File.ReadAllLines("FDIASNC")
               .FirstOrDefault(line => line.StartWith("0128"));

if (line != null)
{
    //Do something with this line
}
```

You don't need to create a `List<string>` since `ReadAllLines` returns `IEnumerable<string>`

If your file is large, you might think to use deferred execution by [`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) instead of loading all lines into memory

Answer (score 1):

```
 RFD.Where(r=>r.Contains("0128")).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select exactly one line, that matches you criteria, use `First` or `Single` LINQ extension method. For example:

```
string str = RFD.First(line => line.StartWith("0128"));
```

returns `0128200313010000330790000033` string

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
using System.Linq;

// later in your program...

foreach (string match in RFD.Where(l => l.StartsWith("0128"))) {
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
string line = RFD.FirstOrDefault(line => line.StartsWith("0128"));
```

If there's no line with 0128 at the beginning then line is null